# Suspend/resume failure on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend

Running a node with E5 2630 V3 and Quadro K620. When I attempt to suspend, the node doesn't suspend but there is no display so I am forced to hard reboot. As seen in the image (link provided), there might be some problem with NVIDIA drivers (nvidia-375) since the error message says **suspend/resume failure non-free:nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia**. Can anyone please help me fix this issue.

[Ubuntu Internal Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hOB.png)